# How can I make my Android LinearLayout weights work with values of 1 and 2?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to make a LinearLayout that has three rows, each of equal height. I am making this using 3 LinearLayouts inside the main one, each with a layout_weight of 1.

The middle LinearLayout should contain an ImageView, TextView, ImageView, with weights of 1,2,1. To do this, inside the middle LinearLayout I created another 3.

I want the TextView to be double the size of each ImageView. If you see the code below, when layout_weight is 1 for the inner LinearLayouts I have no problems, the three appear of equal size. However when I set the middle one (with id=textLayout) to `layout_weight=2`, it completely disappears (as seen in the Eclipse graphical layout viewer) and only the two others are visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutMid"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <TextView
                android:text="Status"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the additional layouts to space the middle row appropriately, and your weights are backwards.  If you want the text to be 2x the outer images, you want it to 1, and the outer columns to be 1.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LayoutTop"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#ffff0000"/>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LayoutMid"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_weight="1.5" />
        <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Status" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
        <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5" android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LayoutBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#ff00ff00"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I used an icon (if you have one) to put a picture in the middle row, and some colors in the top and bottom in to show the spacing more clearly.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get text in the middle and "left" and "right" buttons on each side. Would it be better to use a RelativeLayout?

Comment: you can do the same weighting on the buttons that you do on the image views.  relative layouts are good, but i often have a hard time getting exact "this view is 2x bigger than the other two" solutions with them - especially when you don't know the screen size of the end device

Comment: Actually it doesn't HAVE to be 2x. It will work if the arrows are next to the center TextView. I've tried the following XML for the RelativeLayout and I get the same problem... the TextView is not visible: (this is just the middle "row")

Comment: `code   <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LayoutMid"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MainText"
            android:text="MainText here"
            android:textColor="#0f0f0f"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" /> code`

Comment: `code
       <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/leftImg"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:background="@drawable/icon"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/MainText" />
    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/rightImg"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:background="@drawable/icon"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/MainText" />
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: with the relative layouts, you can't have the textview in a different layout than the imageviews.  using what you posted in the comments you have to have the imageviews be in the LayoutMid and be relative to the MainText, or be relative to the layoutMid